# copy files instead of compiling when building debian package

Tags: apt, java, compiling, deb, dh-make

### The goal

I have been trying to make a very simple debian package for two days now. There is a java application called fits. In ~40 lines, it can be packaged for osx.

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/fits.rb

I would like to make a debian version of this package. I need to do 3 very simple things.

1. Comment out a line in fits.xml that crashes the jvm on ubuntu
   https://github.com/harvard-lts/fits/issues/160
2. Copy the source files to `/usr/share/fits` and symlink `fits.sh` to `/usr/bin/fits`
3. Add java >= 1.7 as a dependency, since fits.sh just calls java.

### The problems

I started off making the debian files myself following [this tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/Intro?action=show&redirect=IntroDebianPackaging).
I couldn't get that to work because debian/rules uses dh, which expects a Makefile to compile the source.

I tried adding a Makefile to source but I get this error

`dpkg-genchanges: error: binary build with no binary artifacts found; cannot distribute`

I tried making a blank build step `build: ;` but I still get an error.

All I want to do is copy files. There is no compile step. I have looked at so many tutorials. All of them have a compile step.

### The questions

Does anyone know how to just copy files when building a debian package?

Or do I have to have some sort of compile step?
And if I have to have a compile step, how can I set up ant for a debian package?

### Files

debian/rules

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@
```

debian/control

```
Source: fits
Section: unknown
Priority: optional
Maintainer: virt <virt@unknown>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>=9)
Standards-Version: 3.9.6
Homepage: <insert the upstream URL, if relevant>

Package: fits
Architecture: any
Depends: ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: harvard file information tool set
```

Comment: Can you please show what `debian/rules` and `debian/control` look like.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Edited just now to add the files

Comment: Try to replace "`Architecture: any`" with "`Architecture: all`".

Comment: Switching any to all didn't resolve the problem. I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214319/i-need-my-debian-rules-file-to-simply-copy-files-to-its-target) which suggested using .install files to copy files, which did work. However now I have a problem where debuild hangs at the dh_strip_nondeterminism step, because I have a lib directory with lots of jars. Is there a way to turn dh_strip_nondeterminism off and just keep the jars anyway?